# Does Spring Batch really prevent executing same jobs concurrently? Is it really idempotent?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I've researched Spring Batch since I have to use it, and I want to know whether Spring Batch can really prevent executing same jobs with same parameters.

In this article, "Same jobs" means "The jobs that have actually same jobName and jobParameters".

I got some points.

- Spring Batch can prevent executing same multiple jobs that executed never before
- Spring Batch can prevent executing the same job after the prior job succeeded

But I have a question: **How about executing same jobs when the last execution was FAILED?**

[image: multiple batch app]

While insepcting Spring Batch codes, I feel this situation possibly occur, but rarely.

```java
    @Override
    public JobExecution createJobExecution(String jobName, JobParameters jobParameters)
            throws JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException, JobRestartException, JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException {

        Assert.notNull(jobName, "Job name must not be null.");
        Assert.notNull(jobParameters, "JobParameters must not be null.");

        /*
         * Find all jobs matching the runtime information.
         *
         * If this method is transactional, and the isolation level is
         * REPEATABLE_READ or better, another launcher trying to start the same
         * job in another thread or process will block until this transaction
         * has finished.
         */

        JobInstance jobInstance = jobInstanceDao.getJobInstance(jobName, jobParameters);
        ExecutionContext executionContext;

        // existing job instance found
        if (jobInstance != null) {

            List<JobExecution> executions = jobExecutionDao.findJobExecutions(jobInstance);

            if (executions.isEmpty()) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot find any job execution for job instance: " + jobInstance);
            }

            // check for running executions and find the last started
            for (JobExecution execution : executions) {
                if (execution.isRunning() || execution.isStopping()) {
                    throw new JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException("A job execution for this job is already running: "
                            + jobInstance);
                }
                BatchStatus status = execution.getStatus();
                if (status == BatchStatus.UNKNOWN) {
                    throw new JobRestartException("Cannot restart job from UNKNOWN status. "
                            + "The last execution ended with a failure that could not be rolled back, "
                            + "so it may be dangerous to proceed. Manual intervention is probably necessary.");
                }
                Collection<JobParameter> allJobParameters = execution.getJobParameters().getParameters().values();
                long identifyingJobParametersCount = allJobParameters.stream().filter(JobParameter::isIdentifying).count();
                if (identifyingJobParametersCount > 0 && (status == BatchStatus.COMPLETED || status == BatchStatus.ABANDONED)) {
                    throw new JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException(
                            "A job instance already exists and is complete for parameters=" + jobParameters
                            + ".  If you want to run this job again, change the parameters.");
                }
            }
            executionContext = ecDao.getExecutionContext(jobExecutionDao.getLastJobExecution(jobInstance));
        }
        else {
            // no job found, create one
            jobInstance = jobInstanceDao.createJobInstance(jobName, jobParameters);
            executionContext = new ExecutionContext();
        }

        JobExecution jobExecution = new JobExecution(jobInstance, jobParameters, null);
        jobExecution.setExecutionContext(executionContext);
        jobExecution.setLastUpdated(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));

        // Save the JobExecution so that it picks up an ID (useful for clients
        // monitoring asynchronous executions):
        jobExecutionDao.saveJobExecution(jobExecution);
        ecDao.saveExecutionContext(jobExecution);

        return jobExecution;

    }
```

This snippet is from SimpleJobRepository of Spring Batch. according to `createJobExecution`, if the job instance already exists and the last execution for the job was failed, the method saves new execution with incremental id.

It is written that "If this method is transactional, and the isolation level is REPEATABLE_READ or better, another launcher trying to start the same job in another thread or process will block until this transaction has finished", however, **even if this method is transactional and isolated with "SERIALIZABLE" level**, it does not use exclusive lock for querying executions of jobs so that another launcher can get last executions at the same time.

Of course once another launcher gets last executions before the first launcher commit the transaction, it will save new execution and do its own task.

I tried to find out whether any hints for preventing this situation, but I couldn't. I need your help. Thank you.

In summary: I think same jobs can be executed twice or more very rarely when multiple batch apps triggered at the same time and the last execution status of the job was FAILED. Am I right? Please give me some hints.

Comment: I don't know if there is a ready made solution for that in spring boot, but nothing is stopping you from storing a flag somewhere in the db, that is being checked at the start of execution, and let that help you decide whether or not to execute the actual batch logic

Comment: Thank you @Stultuske I posted this question just for my curiosity. Maybe I will adopt libraries such as distributed lock. I wanted to check whether Spring Batch itself guarantee idempotent tasks, and lots of article said "Yes, it does" but none of them described how it does in details. That's why I wrote this article.

Answer (score 0):

> How about executing same jobs when the last execution was FAILED?

The method that creates job executions is designed to be transactional. As mentioned in the docs you shared, the isolation level `REPEATABLE_READ` should work in most cases. If this is not sufficient (ie you still see concurrent job executions being launched for the same job instance), then you need to increase the isolation level to `SERIALIZABLE`. That would really serialize concurrent access at the database level, and Spring Batch can do nothing about it.

Now to answer your question about the failure case, once you have a `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level set on your job repository, the lucky winner  (process or thread) who will be able to access the `createJobExecution` method will check the existence of a job instance with the given name and identifying job parameters, and if there is already a failed execution, a new execution for the same job instance will be created to resume the job from where it left off in the previous run.